To what extent do results on bridged graphs generalize to weighted bridged graphs?

A graph G is bridged if each cycle C of length at least four contains two vertices whose
distance from each other in G is strictly less than that in C

(From Bridged graphs and geodesic convexity)
Note this is NOT the same bridged graph as defined by Wikipedia or Wolfram
A natural extension of bridged graphs are weighted bridged graphs in which distance is defined by the sum of edge weights.  However, many proofs for theorems seem to rely on the fact that a bridge must contain less edges than the corresponding arc in the cycle.  This may not hold when we consider weighted bridged graphs.
I would expect that in order for results on bridged graphs to hold, some conditions on the edge weights of a weighted bridged graphs must hold.
Something along the lines of requiring the max edge weight $e_{\text{max}}$ and min edge weight $e_{\text{min}}$ satisfy $e_{\text{max}} < \delta e_{\text{min}}$ for some $\delta > 1$.
($\delta = 1$ would make this equivalent to an unweighted graph).
This would allow (to some extent) the unweighted edge property where a path with less edges will always be shorter than a path with more edges.  However, for long enough paths, this still falls apart.
I'm wondering if there are any results on weighted bridged graphs.
A particular theorem I'm hoping to find the generalization for weighted bridged graph is the following

Theorem 3.1. I f G is a bridged graph, then every cycle in G is well-bridged.


Theorem 3.5. Suppose G is a bridged graph. Then every cycle in G is properly
well-bridged.

(From On local convexity in graphs)

I believe you've mistakenly linked the same article twice.

Oops fixed......
